# Galois group of an irreducible biquadratic polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

We have studied that the Galois group of the splitting field of an irreducible biquadratic polynomial like $x^4+ax^2+b$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$ over $\mathbb Q$ can be $\mathbb Z_{2}\times \mathbb Z_{2}$,$\mathbb Z_{4}$ or $D_4$. We have proven this by taking into account the values of $b$ and $\Delta=a^2-4b$, and the Galois group changed based on the fact if they were squares or not (actually I think we checked if $b$ was a square in $Q(\sqrt\Delta)$ if I remember well).
However, I am having a hard time because I don't understand how we have been able to prove this, and what are the cases in which I could say only by looking at the polynomial what is its Galois group. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

We can determine the Galois group with these theorems:

> Let be $q(x)=x^4+bx^2+c\in k[x]$ irreducible polynomial  over $k$ and has two distict roots $\alpha, \beta$ and $G=\mathrm{Gal}(k(\alpha, \beta),k)$ then

> $1)$ if $\sqrt c \in k$ then $G\cong\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$
> $2)$ if $\sqrt c \notin k$ and $\sqrt{c(b^2-4c)} \in k $ then $G\cong\mathbb Z_4$ and $q_1(x)=x^2+bx+c$ irreducible over $k(\sqrt c)$

> $3)$  if $\sqrt c \notin k$ and $\sqrt{c(b^2-4c)} \notin k $ then $G\cong D_4$ and $q_1(x)=x^2+bx+c$ irreducible over $k(\sqrt c)$

Comment: Is there a reference for that theorem? I would like to see a proof.